# Google Image Search using Android

Tags: google-search

I have an image on my smartphone and I want to paste it into Google Image Search to see if I can get similar images.

I can do this by pasting the image using desktop but not using Android ...

Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 4):

Instructions performed on Firefox for Android on stock Android 6.0.1.

1. Switch to Desktop mode in your preferred browser (it changes the user-agent).
2. Open *https://images.google.com* and tap the camera icon next to the search bar on the page.
3. Tap Upload an image
4. From the bottom sheet pick **Documents**. (This option might not be available in some Android versions.)

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
5. In the left pane, select Images or Internal Storage and select your image file. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [search apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_search#group_1061) available which may assist you here, for example [Search By Image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.palmteam.imagesearch) (using Google/Tineye/Yandex image reverse search engine). This app lets you pick an image from your gallery (or take a new one with your camera), perform some basic editing (crop/rotate), and then fires a corresponding search for similar images.

The list initially linked (disclaimer: link goes to my own site) gives you some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for reverse image search from a smartphone:

1. Click [here](https://ctrlq.org/google/images/) to visit Ctrlq.org.
2. There you will find Reverse Image Search option (Google's official) and within there you will see the *Upload* button. (It will allow to choose from camera and gallery.) Click on it and select an image.

This will search and display to you related images on your mobile phone.