# How search for similar images in the phone?

Tags: browser, images, search, google-search, media-search

I am looking for an equivalent functionality that is available on the desktop Google Search page: upload an image and search for similar ones.

Unfortunately once Google recognizes that I am on the phone, search with image gets disabled.

I also tried with DuckDuckGo.com but again I cannot find this option that is readily available once I am browsing on the desktop pc.

Can someone recommend a search engine that offers image search on the mobile?

Or alternatively simple way to fool DuckDuckGo or Google to let me search with image...

Comment: There is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkfree.searchbyimage) that claims to do reverse search. I haven't used it

Comment: According to Google support, you should be able to search. See support.google.com/websearch/answer/…. You have to put the browser in **desktop mode**. I just tried and it works

Comment: Indeed this one: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181506/google-image-search-using-android solves the problem.